# File name convention for Fortran unformatted output

Tags: coding-style, fortran

Even though any file name would be valid and unformatted output has limitations in portability I would still like to ask if there is a file name convention (like adding a suffix) often / usually applied for unformatted Fortran output?

Comment: No there isn't, make one up that suits your local requirements and get on with some more interesting problem.  If this comment leaves you dissatisfied then replace the first sentence with *Yes, use `.dat`.*

Comment: My convention (based on what I typically output) is .raw for outputting big-endian 32-bit floats. For 2D arrays I suffix _LD128 for e.g. an array with leading dimension of length 128, so that it's obvious how to read it in from another program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from High Performance Mark answers my question:

```
YOUR_FILE.dat
```